# Promo code not working on mobile device for Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, add-on

I've set up a basic promo code for all users to be able to use once. The promo code works fine on a desktop browser. When I try the promo code on a mobile browser, I can't access the 2nd page of my checkout process. After I've entered the promo code and selected continue, the same page reloads. I don't get any errors or anything. If I remove the promo code and select continue, the 2nd page loads fine.

I'm using EE 2.8.1 and Expresso Store 2.5.1

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this issue with Expresso Store Promo Codes not working? I'm having issues with the promo code on mobile browsers and in IE. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the 'Limit per customer' option set to 1. This will allow users to only use the coupon code once IF they have an account with your site and are signed in when they use the coupon. Otherwise, it only allows the coupon to be used once and that was causing my issue. I removed the limit per customer option and everything works.